# Bug in google cloud bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I observed something very strange today when trying to steam records into bigquery table , sometimes after the successful stream, it shows all the records being steamed into, something it only shows part of it? What I did was I deleted the table, and recreated it. Has anyone encountered any scenario like this? I am seriously concerned.

Many thanks.

Regards,

Comment: Is this similar to the issue described in here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53157437/streaming-buffer-google-bigquery

Comment: Note that streaming data [should be available shortly](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability) after the first streaming insertion. Could you clarify how only "part of your data" is being shown? Does your query contains warnings while begin completed?

Comment: Hi, I could see the number of records in my process steaming into bigquery data shows the complete number of records, however, when I did a count on the bigquery, it showed less number of records though. But if I waited after up to one and a half hours and recreated the table with the same table name, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced a similar issue after deleting and recreating the table in a short time span, which is part of our e2e testing plan. As long as you do not delete/recreate your table streaming API works great. In our case workaround was to customize streaming table suffix for e2e execution only.

I am not sure it this was addressed or not, but I would expect constant improvement.

I've also created [a test project reproducing the issue](https://github.com/adrianwit/bqstreamissue)  and shared it with BigQuery team.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience.

Comment: np, I took us a while to pin the issue down, you always assume that there is a problem with your software first, knowing other experience the same help and also e2e testing makes it clear.